# Get new Id + 1 for each group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Please help me to figure out a way of getting from a data set the first number id of each group IF the Id is not already taken yet... I don't even know to explain it, So I will explain down here:

```
Id    | Col1  | Col2 | Value    |  Number
------+-------+------+----------+-------
17525 | A     |  B   | 1086.00  |  1
17525 | A     |  B   | 1086.00  |  2
17525 | A     |  B   | 1086.00  |  3
17526 | A     |  B   | 1378.00  |  1
17526 | A     |  B   | 1378.00  |  2
17526 | A     |  B   | 1378.00  |  3
17527 | A     |  B   | 1498.00  |  1
17527 | A     |  B   | 1498.00  |  2
17527 | A     |  B   | 1498.00  |  3
```

And I want to get something like this:
For each Id OR Value (doesn't matter, are equal) the FIRST Number, after the FIRST already taken from the other group.

Something like this:

```
Id    | Col1  | Col2 | Value    |  Number
------+-------+------+----------+-------
17525 | A     |  B   | 1086.00  |  1
17526 | A     |  B   | 1378.00  |  2
17527 | A     |  B   | 1498.00  |  3
```

So for the first value, 1086.00 I'll take Number 1, for the 2nd value 1378.00 I'll will take Number 2, because 1 is already taken be the first value.

I tried for 3 hours, with ROW_NUMBER, doesn't work, Recursion CTE could't pass the Max Recursion Limit 100  error.

Please HELP!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)?:

```
select distinct Id, Col1, Col2, Value
  , dr = dense_rank() over (order by Id)
from t
```

returns:

```
+-------+------+------+---------+----+
|  Id   | Col1 | Col2 |  Value  | dr |
+-------+------+------+---------+----+
| 17525 | A    | B    | 1086,00 |  1 |
| 17526 | A    | B    | 1378,00 |  2 |
| 17527 | A    | B    | 1498,00 |  3 |
+-------+------+------+---------+----+
```

Comment: I think you should order by Value.

Comment: @AlexanderSharovarov Perhaps. The question says "Id OR Value (doesn't matter, are equal) "

Comment: Omg... I tought that dense_rank() is not suported in SQL2008R2 ! I have to test this... Thank you very much !!!